# how do I do a complex conditional in dust.js?

Tags: html, node.js, templates, dust.js

Understanding that the `if` statement has been deprecated, how would I implement something like the following in dust?

I have a template with the following psuedocode:

```
<div class="cities">{#city.name}Welcome to
   {if ..length > 10} <br>
   {.}
{/city.name}</div>
```

with the aim of inserting a `<br>` linebreak if the `city` in question has a `name` field that is longer than 10 characters. Is there a way to, for instance, use the `select` operator to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Dust has a `gt` filter that should do what you're looking for. Something like:

```
<div class="cities">
    {#city}
        {@gt key=name.length value="10" type="number"}<br/>{/gt}
        {name}
    {/city}
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, for some reason that's not triggering the `gt` filter, even though I'm using exactly this code...

Comment: Can you post your full code and an example of your JSON data?

Comment: ah it turns out that I didn't have the helpers from linkedin installed, all is well now. thanks!